# How to create a function which multiply the quantity of the product to the cost and add to the total cost, 18% of that?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, frontend

Let's say I have 10 bottles of water with the price of 0,8cent for each one, I need to find the total cost of 10 bottles so I multiply 10 by 0,8 which makes 8,00$. Next I need to find 18% of 8$ and add it to 8$. I wrote some code but it shows that the result is not a function:

```
function multyAll(quantity, oneCost) {
 quantity = prompt('Insert quantity')
 oneCost = prompt('Insert the cost')
let mul = quantity * oneCost;
function totalPer() {
    let percent = (mul * 18) / 100
return percent
}
return mul
}
let result = multyAll(12, 0.8)
console.log(result())
```

Comment: `net * (1 + vat_prcnt) = total` !? ...`total / (1+vat_prcnt) = net` ;) (* 10,*100,*x)

Comment: You're not doing anything with `totalPer()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to reassign your parameters in your function, since they're what's passed to it for your values. Your error message "result is not a function" is because you're console logging result() (the parentheses mean you want to run the function, but result isn't a function, it's the result of a function). I believe this code should solve your problems

```js
function calculatePrice(quantity, unitPrice, taxRate){
    const subtotal = quantity * unitPrice;
    const total = subtotal + (subtotal * taxRate);
    return total;
}

console.log(calculatePrice(10, .8, .18)); // outputs $9.44
```

This function takes 10 units (bottles of water) and multiplies them by their unit price ($.80), and adds the amount in tax to that result (you said 18%).

Comment: Can you please tell me why in this example we can call doCount as a function? 

function makeCounter() { 
var count = 0;
    function counter() {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
}
return counter;
}
var doCount = makeCounter(); 
console.log(doCount());
console.log(doCount());
console.log(doCount());

Comment: and it doesn't show that doCount is not a function

Comment: @RustinWilde This is because your makeCounter function returns a function (counter). It returns the function itself, so doCount = the return value of makeCounter (the function, counter)

Answer (score 0):

you wrote console.log(result()) in last line, should be console.log(result) without parentheses after result. You getting result is not a function because resoult is variable and adding parathesis after it javascript angine wants to invoke it as function.